# How to update all records in a table at the same time (without updating records one by one) using stored procedure

Tags: sql-update

I have a table named Emp wit (Empname,Details).  There are 4 records in the table.  I want to update all records with a single update statement, without updating records one by one, using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE [tableName] SET [columnName] = [value] WHERE [condition]
```